# Idiom wanted for means and ends

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

There is a common Russian expression, literally translated as "winners are not judged". The meaning is that one can get away with cutting corners and/or employing less-than-wholesome means in pursuit of some goal, provided one actually achieves the goals. In other words "the ends justify the means, so long as you actually achieve the ends".

Is there a compact English idiom for this notion?

Comment: What's wrong with "The end justifies the means"?

Comment: The bare quote is giving a thumbs up from the commentator rather than decrying or at least querying the 'winning is everything' attitude.

Comment: @Robusto "The end justifies the means" doesn't capture the conditional nature of the justification - the means are justified if they worked but not otherwise. Usually this expression implies a measure of cynicism.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Indeed. Like I said, it's a somewhat cynical phrase.

Comment: _History is written by the victor_ is perhaps closer.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: Indeed. Like I said.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: That is also implied in the English expression...

Comment: In grad school, the saying was "A B pays the bills." In other words, you must only pass the class to keep your stipend. The implication was that your time should be spent on your research, not classwork.

Comment: It is also reminiscent of the old joke: what do you call a man who was last in his class in med school? Doctor.

Comment: A related concept - *The Golden Rule: he who has the gold makes the rules*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondered why no-one else had suggested the *definitive* answer, until I ran a Google search that showed it to be much more common here in Australia than anywhere else.

> **Winners are grinners.**

or its long form

> **Winners are grinners and the losers can please themselves.**

It is particularly apt that last night a high-profile (Australian) sportsman ["won" a boxing match at the end of 10 rounds](http://wwos.ninemsn.com.au/article.aspx?id=8607481) because his (South African) opponent believed the poster that said "12 Round Title Fight". Winners are grinners captures the spirit perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

A [well-known saying](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22History%20is%20written%20by%20the%20victors%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (often attributed to Churchill, though I can't find any evidence for this) is...

> *History is written by the victors.*

...which I think is the standard English version of OP's translation from a Russian equivalent, given that he seems to be looking for something conveying an element of *cynicism **after** the event*, rather than the *self-justification **before** the event* often implicit in *"The end justifies the means"*.

Answer (score 5):

Inasmuch as breaking rules to achieve one's objectives can lead to harsh judgement, [U.S. Navy Admiral Grace Hopper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) observed:

**It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission.**

which is also reported, in this variant:

**If it's a good idea, go ahead and do it. It is much easier to apologize than it is to get permission.**

Although this doesn't have exactly the same meaning as "winners are not judged" it does imply that winners who break the rules are judged less harshly, if they are judged at all.

I hear this often in the U.S. and abide by it myself at times.

Comment: I like this - it certainly does capture the spirit. If there are no other suggestions for a few days, I'll accept  it.

Comment: Rear Admiral Hopper quite likely wasn't the origin of that phrase, but she did make heavy use of it, and if anyone deserves to be considered its patron, so to speak, it's her.

Answer (score 0):

[*to the victor go the spoils*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+victor+belong+the+spoils), alternatively [*winner take all*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/winner+take+all)

These idioms are not usually applied to explain or excuse actions morally, but they are sometimes. Consider the idiom famously attributed (incorrectly) to Winston Churchill, "[history is written by the victors.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5597/is-history-always-written-by-the-victors/5599#5599)"

The application in this form would mean that in some competitions, (such as war or love) even the truth is a trophy, even the facts concerning what has occurred can change to further benefit the champion.

Also make note of the comments on the OP, [the ends justify the means](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+end+justifies+the+means) (or its varients, "the ends never justify the means," "the means justify the ends,") is an idiom in its own right.